# how i can execute windows batch file from UNIX-AIX?

Tags: unix, command-line, windows-server-2003, aix, copssh

How can I execute windows batch files from UNIX-AIX, where I installed copssh?

Comment: oh i'm sorry i mean UNIX

Comment: Do you want the batch file to execute on the AIX machine or a Windows machine?

Comment: i write `.bat` file and store it in `c:\scan.bat` ..... now i want to execute this file from UNIX_AIX ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work? From the Unix box:

```
$ rsh -l user_name windows_host_name "C:\scan.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless it's very basic, i.e. it doesn't call any Windows specific programs, in which case you're probably better off transcoding it to bash or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be translating it into bash.

Answer (score 1):

Check out 
[winexe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinExe).